# SoftException in Application.cpp:249: can't acces file

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site with news messages.

And in my `.htacces` file I have this line of code.

```
RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)/?$ events.php?id=$1
```

If I go to mysite.com/index/event/1 I get an `500 internal server error`

The weird thing is that if I change the  `.htacces` to

```
RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)/?$ nieuws_read.php?id=$1
```

I don't get that error and the page works correctly.

How is it possible that it doesn't work with all files.

I got this error

```
    [Tue May 27 17:46:41 2014] [error] [client ipadress] SoftException in Application.cpp:249: File "/../../../../public_html/new/events.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://new.mysite.eu/index/events
[Tue May 27 17:46:41 2014] [error] [client ipadress] Premature end of script headers: events.php, referer: http://new.mysite.eu/index/events
[Tue May 27 17:46:41 2014] [error] [client ipadress] File does not exist: /../../../../public_html/new/500.shtml, referer: http://new.mysite.eu/index/events
```

I hope I gave you enough info.
Thx

Comment: First step ALLWAYS is to check the error logs. 500 alone is not very usefull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the filepermissions.

I once got that same error, I changed the filepermissions form `666` to `644`

Answer (score 13):

It's a permission issue. The one-liner command below should fix it.

You'll need to change the `username:apache` part below to the user:group names of your http server. Group on Apache is often `apache`, on Nginx it's `www-data`.

**First `cd` into your website public directory.**

```
sudo chmod 2775 . && sudo chown -R username:apache . && sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g=rwxs "{}" \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod g=rw  "{}" \; && sudo setfacl -d -m g::rwx . && sudo setfacl -d -m o::rx .
```

This will make those permissions persistent to all new files copied to or created in this folder.

Then you can view your new permissions with:

```
getfacl .
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue but it happened with the wp-content folder in my WordPress site. I searched and [found solution from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808245/softexception-in-application-cpp249-cant-acces-file), only need to change folder permission from 777 to 755 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> How to change ownership on the files and folders go to CWP.admin Left
>   Menu –> User Accounts — > Fix Permissions and select user.

[Offical fix](http://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/500-internal-server-error)