# Wordpress error 500 before installation

Tags: wordpress

I try to install wordpress in subfolder on my WWW server. I downloaded clear wordpress from direct page (wordpress.org) and upload this content to folder on my server. When files has been uploaded and i try to go to install page browser returns "The xxx server can not handle this request now."

I have tested all the solutions on the Internet with a .htaccess file, allocating 64M memory, but none of them works.I also tried to change the PHP version to a newer / older version and upload files to the main directory on the server. Where is problem?

@EDIT - server logs

```
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:30:29 +0200] "GET /wordpress HTTP/1.1" 301 246 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:30:29 +0200] "GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:30:29 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:30:37 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:30:37 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:30:38 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:32:14 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:32:19 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:36:50 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:36:51 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - "xxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:36:56 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 769 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:37:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 745 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:37:26 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 745 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:37:28 +0200] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 212 "xxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:37:38 +0200] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 256 "xxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:37:39 +0200] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 256 "xxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:37:40 +0200] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 256 "xxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:37:40 +0200] "GET /test/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1075 "xxxtest/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:43:10 +0200] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 354 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:49:16 +0200] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:49:16 +0200] "GET /test/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:50:27 +0200] "GET /test/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:16:50:28 +0200] "GET /test/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:04:23 +0200] "GET /wordpress HTTP/1.1" 301 246 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:04:23 +0200] "GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:04:23 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:07:23 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 755 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:21:09 +0200] "GET /wp HTTP/1.1" 301 239 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:21:09 +0200] "GET /wp/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:21:09 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:21:40 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:21:42 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:21:42 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:21:42 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:21:43 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:21:44 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:23:10 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:23:11 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - "xxxwp/wp-admin/setup-config.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:23:48 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:27:51 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:27:52 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:28:18 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:29:28 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:34:26 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:34:26 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - "xxxwp/wp-admin/setup-config.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:42:23 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
userip - - [27/Apr/2018:17:42:24 +0200] "GET /wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
```

@EDIT #2 - error log

```
[Fri Apr 27 18:15:54 2018] [error] [client 155.133.70.149] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/xxx/public_html/wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php" is writeable by group
[Fri Apr 27 18:15:48 2018] [error] [client 155.133.70.149] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/xxx/public_html/wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php" is writeable by group
[Fri Apr 27 17:23:10 2018] [alert] [client 155.133.70.149] /home/xxx/public_html/wp/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: Make sure all WordPress files were correctly uploaded to the server. If, after that, your site is still throwing the error then check your server's error log and post the contents here so we can help.

Comment: @cabrerahector I am sure that all files have uploaded correctly. I add today server logs into the edit

Comment: You have, at least, one core WP file missing showing in your log: `"GET /wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 404`. Reupload all files again just to be sure, rewriting existing files when prompted.

Comment: @cabrerahector The problem is that I checked if this file exists physically on the server. And it is - I even changed his chmod to 777 as part of debugging

Comment: Try "chmodding" folders to 755 and files to 644 and check again.

Comment: @cabrerahector This is from when I uploaded files to the server - 755 folders, files in 644 folders.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, then. Hopefully someone else will hop on to help understand what's going on (or if you figure it out by yoursef, don't forget you can answer your own question too!) Good luck!

Comment: Does your server have an error log you can look in? That'd help you figure what's causing the 500 error.

Comment: @mcon I've uploaded the error log as edit

Comment: @montana have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808245/softexception-in-application-cpp249-cant-acces-file) already?